# How is the slidable menu in the YouTube app called?

Tags: android, web

I want to replicate the slidable menu in the YouTube app, which allows you to remove a video from your playlist. My Google search came away empty handed, probably because of a lack of specific terminology.

[GIF of the menu](https://imgur.com/WeC0oVW)

Comment: As per https://m3.material.io/foundations/interaction/gestures#a56fdfc3-5d7a-411a-8414-db9a1b0fca54 , it is called Swipe gesture on component.